How do I tell testCompile phase of maven to look for imported .java file under src/main/java?
I had just pulled a project from SVN in IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition 2024.1.2) and I had the following problem:
The project directory looks like:
src
+main
 +java
  +com.mycompany  /*Edit: it is indeed com/mycompany on disk */
   -somepackage
   -MyApplication
+test
 +java
  +com.mycompany  /*Edit: it is com/mycompany on disk too */
   -MyApplicationTests

I have a test class MyApplicationTests, and the MyApplicationTests.java file looks like:
package com.mycompany;

import com.mycompany.somepackage.Someclass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class mycompanyApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private Someclass someclass;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        //do something using someclass
    }

}

When I Ctrl+click on the imported class Someclass
the editor jumps to the definition under src/main/java.
During the build process, the phases
clean
resources
compile
testResources

had succeeded without error.
this test class failed to compile at the testCompile phase, giving error like:
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/.../src/test/java/com/mycompany/somepackage/Someclass.java:[12,33] package com.mycompany.somepackage does not exist

It seems the testCompile phase of maven is looking for the imported class in src/test/java instead of src/main/java.
I am trying to workaround by copying the whole com.mycompany.somepackage sources from src/main/java to src/test/java.
But I feel it is not the right way. You have to copy dependency of dependencies under src/main/java. It is a long process to copy all the files and it’s blocking the editor while copying.
How do I fix this? Is this expected behaviour of testCompile?

+com.mycompany is wrong. That should be two directories, not one So in your notation, that should be +com +mycompany

If your package naming and folder structure is correct, this will happen automatically. As g00se says, if your classes are currently in a directory called com.mycompany, that is wrong, they should be in directory mycompany in directory com (in /src/main/java).

I just checked it is src/main/java/com/mycompany/**several folders of packages** on disk, and IntelliJ IDEA displays the folders com/mycompany/ as one folder named com.mycompany(perhaps because it is regarded as a package?).

How exactly do you trigger the build? Can you share the Run Configuration IDEA creates for it? Does the issue persist when you run "mvn compiler:testCompile" from OS Command Prompt?
